# Tab Groups - Any API

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way to use the high-level APIs to detect whether a tab is in the active Panorama group? It seems there's no mention of the tab group a tab belongs to in the [`tabs`](https://stackoverflow.com/) module, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a way.

I don't know how to get the XUL tab with the SDK, but I know it's possible as I recall people posting questions that did this. Maybe @canuckistani you can help us get the xul `tab`.

Anyways once you have the `tab` then you can access it's property `_tabViewTabItem`. And from here you can do whatever you want. Like figure out the group id of the tab by going `tab._tabViewTabItem.parent.id` Or change group id's.

Here is some code, the first two lines are non-sdk code.

```
var tab = gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[10]; //non sdk code
gBrowser.selectedTab = tab; //non sdk code
console.log(tab._tabViewTabItem.parent.id) //works both in sdk and non-sdk
```

Note: pinned tabs dont have the `_tabViewTabItem` property. So thats how you can tell if its pinned.

```
var tabs = gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes;
for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
  try {
   console.log(tabs[i]._tabViewTabItem.parent.id);
  } catch(ex) {
    console.warn('tab ' + i + ' ex:', ex);
    console.log('its probably pinned')
  }
}
```

Comment: Intereting... thanks! Will try this some time if I go back to playing with it.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are no plans to provide a tab group api - the 'panorama' feature in Firefox has not proved to be very popular, so there may not be much benefit vs focusing on other features.

Comment: Sigh, I worried as much. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The [Tab Groups](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-groups-panorama/) extension stores it's data using [SessionStore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsISessionStore).

```
var tabData = JSON.parse(SessionStore.getTabValue(tab,"tabview-tab"));
console.log(tabData.groupID); // 3
```

Data about the groups themselves is stored on the browser.xul object (ie. ownerGlobal). Data specific to each group is stored as "tabview-group" and other data is stored as "tabview-groups".

```
var groupsData = JSON.parse(SessionStore.getWindowValue(tab.ownerGlobal, 'tabview-groups'));
console.log(groupsData); // Object { nextID: 4,
                                    activeGroupId: 3,
                                    activeGroupName: "Third Group",
                                    totalNumber: 2 }

var groupData = JSON.parse(SessionStore.getWindowValue(tab.ownerGlobal, 'tabview-group'));
console.log(tabData[3].title); // Third Group
```